# Evaluating conditional probability for a cipher text given a plain text message

Tags: probability, random-variables, cryptography, conditional-probability

I'm not posting this on Cryptography as I have not even understood the math for this, and this had nothing to do with the cryptographic definition inside. [Caesar cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesar_cipher) should give enough context, if required.

The cipher works as follows: There is a set of messages $M$ that are strings over the English alphabets $\{a, b, ... z\}$, and a set of keys $K = \{0, 1, ... 25\}$. To encrypt a message, we pick a key k uniformly at random and shift each letter in the word k times. If $'o'$ is the letter and $3$ is the key then it becomes $'r'$ upon encryption. The set of cipher texts is $C$.

Assume the following messages and their distribution.
$\textbf{M} = \{"one", "ten"\}$ and $P[M="one"] = 0.5, P[M="ten"] = 0.5$. 
Key space is $\textbf{K} = \{0, 1, 2 ... 25\}$ as usual. With each key occurring with equal probability $1/26$. Random variables $M\ and\ K$ are independent.

We are required to find the probability that the cipher text is $"rqh"$.

My reasoning is that, the two messages form a partition of the message space and hence, the law of total probability applies.

\begin{align*}
P[C="rqh"] &= P[C="rqh" and\ M="one"] + P[C="rqh" and\ M="ten"] (due\ to\ law\ of\ total\ probability)\\ &= P[C="rqh" | M = "one"] * P[M = "one"] + P[C="rqh" | M = "ten"] * P[M = "ten"] (by\ definition\ of\ conditional\ probability)\\ &= {1/26} * 0.5 + 0 * 0.5 (how\ did\ this\ happen\ ?!) = 1/52
\end{align*}

$P[C="rqh" | M = "one"]$ is taken as equal to the probability that, the particular key that caused the shift, was chosen ($k = 3$ produces the desired shift here). How did these two quantities equate ? The first one involves two random variables $M\ and\ C$ while the second appears to be obtained from the probability that the third random variable $K$ took on $3$. Please help me understand this relation.

After this, we prove that the apriori probability of $M$ being $"ten"$ and the aposteriori probability of it being $"ten"$ are not the same hence there is no perfect secrecy. I can understand this part.

Please explain how $P[C="rqh" | M = "one"] = 1/26$ was obtained.

Sorry for the terrible typesetting, I'm still learning to use LaTeX. If some one can fix the equations, I can learn from your edit.

Example taken from: [perfects secrecy part ii by Prof. Katz via Coursera](https://www.coursera.org/learn/cryptography/lecture/wXerf/perfect-secrecy-part-ii).

Comment: You should move the Caesar cipher note at the beginning. Anyway, you have $26$ keys, if you encode $one$ with each of the keys ($26$ events) the encoded text will be $rqh$ only once. See this as the drawings from a fair (26 sided) dice, the probability is ${1\over 26}$

Comment: @N74 I still did not understand. Could you explain in simpler terms, please ?

Comment: What in my description is not clear?

Comment: @N74 Thanks for your comment. Intuitively, your description is clear. You claim that, given "one" is the message the only way "rqh" can occur is key k =3 was chosen at random. So you say P[C="rqh"|M="one"] = P[K=3]. Again, I can appreciate this fact, intuitively. But as you can see there are two random variables involved in the left hand side, but the right hand side has a totally different one, K. What is the actual mathematics behind this equation ? Could explain in terms of what the probability space is and how things relate exactly, please ?

Comment: $C=rqh$ and $M=one$ are samples, not random variables. You are only using the definition of $K$ in this part.

Comment: @N74 Consider a different distribution on key length.

Comment: @N74 Consider a different distribution on key length. Keys can be of length 1, 2 or 3, each with probability 0.3, 0.3, 0.4. What happens to P[C="rqh"|M="one"] now ? (If key length does not equal plain text length, say, it is repeated to match the length). So it can be of length 1, and be k=3 or length 2, and k =33 or length 3 and k = 333. Will this term now evaluate to $(Pr[keylen=1&k=3]+P[keylen=2&k=33]+P[keylen=3&k=333]) = (0.3*(1/26)+(0.3)*(1/26^{2}) + (0.4)*(1/26^{3}))$ ? Is my understanding correct ?

Comment: You mean something like $P(K=3)=0.5$? In that case, obviously, $P(C=rqh|M=one)=0.5$ just like $P(C=r|M=o)$ or  $P(C=q|M=n)$ or  $P(C=h|M=e)$. Obviously we can say nothing about $P(C=b|M=a)$ which corresponds to $K=1$, this confirms that we are only using the properties of $K$.

Comment: Ok ignore my last comment, maybe I understood what you are missing. You don't have a different key for each letter, you have a single key for the whole message. You are not sampling a key for each letter in it, maybe the lecture you attended was not clear about it.

Comment: What you had in mind is more like a Vigenére cipher: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vigenère_cipher

Comment: Key lengths are random. Offset digits in the key are obtained at random too. Say, if key length turned out to be 3 (with Pr 0.4), it can be any of 3 letter shift strings over the numbers $\{0, 1, ... 25\}$ say "371" or "173". Each should have equal probability of occurring. Also, if message was longer, then we keep repeating the digits. Say Key length = 3 and K = "0-2-12" and message = "hello" we match and shift it with the key: "0-2-12-0-2". Sorry, this is in the context of problem definition, I should have described it clearly. But what is $P[C="rqh"|M="one"]$ now ?

Comment: As I told you this is similar to a Vigenére cipher. If you want an answer on this copy your last comment in a new question, along with the evaluation you made for the apriori probability. but what you have in the OP is correct for a Caesar cipher.